# @ symbol in C++ comments

Tags: c++, comments

I'm learning C++, and while setting up VS Code I found the following in one of its tutorials.

It's just a demo program. But my question is about the convention of using the `@` symbol in the comments as... titles?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

/**
* @brief An example program. This program demonstrates simple vector storage and element iteration.
*        A welcome string is output to the user.
*
* @return Returns 0 when execution completes succesfully.
*/

int main() {
   ...
}
```

It's just a style question.

Comment: see https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html

Comment: Check out doxygen comments

Comment: It's a symbol used by a tool, doxygen, that parses the source file and turns the marked comments into more formal documentation.

Comment: If you don't like the `@`, you can also use `'\'`, as in `\brief`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ is a symbol used by a tool, [Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/index.html), that parses the source file and turns the marked comments into more formal documentation.

For details see [Documenting the Code](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) in the [Doxygen documentation.](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/index.html)